# How can I use a variable in batch script at sqlldr?

Tags: batch-file, sql-loader

I have a variable in batch script and I want to use this variable at `sqlloader` code for infile. How can I do?

Comment: elaborate your question, as of now it makes no sense to anybody.

Comment: ok, I defined a variable in batch script for a directory and I want to use this in sqlloader control file. I'm going to use this variable in sqlloader control file for 'infile'. thnks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question.

my variable is **directory_name** in batch script.
i define this variable like **set directory_name = C:\a\b.csv**.
And i use this variable in sqlloader control file **infile '%directory_name%'**.

thanks.

Comment: with `set` don't use spaces before and after the equal sign. This (these) space(s) would be part of the variablename or the value

Comment: you are true. i written these spaces mistakenly. sorry for this.