# SQL LOADER - How to pass data file as a variable?

Tags: batch-file, sql-loader

I have a SQL loader command which I am calling from a batch script. The data filename is not constant. We have a timestamp appended to it each time the file is generated and populated. So my batch file gets this data file in a variable `Fname`.

```
SET Fname=dir C:\Temp\TEST_*.dat /b
```

Now, when the `Sqlldr` commmand runs from the batch file

```
sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='C:\Temp\TEST.ctl' LOG='C:\Temp\TEST.log' DATA= %Fname%
```

I get the error

```
LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'data'
```

I cannot enclose the variable `Fname` in single quotes. That does not work.

I checked [How can I use a variable in batch script at sqlldr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858167/)

If I use the method specified in the discussion above and include it in the ctl file as **infile** `%Fname%` I still get the error as the variable `Fname` appears as `dir C:\Temp\TEST_*.dat /b` and I get error saying file not found.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you know that
INFILE '$somedir/$somefile'
is a valid syntax inside the control file (in Unix of course) and it will be correctly resolved by sqlldr. I did not know that until recently. Oracle should award anybody who finds where it is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution below executes the command always with first `TEST_*.dat` file found in folder `C:\Temp`.

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\Temp\TEST_*.dat") do (
    sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='C:\Temp\TEST.ctl' LOG='C:\Temp\TEST.log' "DATA=%%F"
    goto AfterLoop
)
:AfterLoop
```

A perhaps better solution is executing the command always with newest `TEST_*.dat` file found in folder `C:\Temp` according to last modification date.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir "C:\Temp\TEST_*.dat" /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do (
    sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='C:\Temp\TEST.ctl' LOG='C:\Temp\TEST.log' "DATA=%%F"
    goto AfterLoop
)
:AfterLoop
```

It would be possible to assign the name of the found file to an environment variable inside the FOR loop and run the command below `AfterLoop`. But this requires additional code to check if at least 1 file was found in the folder.

Those batch code snippets were developed using the help information output by running in a command prompt window `for /?` and `dir /?`.

`2^>nul` is redirecting the error output of command `dir` to device NUL if no file is found in folder to suppress the unwanted error message for this special use case.

My last hint:

In batch files always specify applications to run with full path and file extension (in double quotes if space in path/file name) to avoid being dependent on directories in environment variable **PATH**, except this is not possible as storage location of application executable is not known on batch execution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the for loop code

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\Temp\TEST_*.dat") do (
    sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='C:\Temp\TEST.ctl' LOG='C:\Temp\TEST.log' "DATA=%%F"
    goto AfterLoop
)
:AfterLoop
```

and this worked.

I do not have the problem of multiple files as after I load it everytime, I move the file to a different folder. So at any given point I expect only one file.